# Angular Validator requiredFalse

Tags: angular, validation, boolean, requiredfieldvalidator, variable-names

I want to add a validator to my FormControl that validates the form if a boolean is false.
There is `requiredTrue` but I need the opposite. Is there a validator for `requiredFalse`?

1. `this.myForm.controls.existObjectsWithThisStudyIdControl.addValidators(Validators.requiredFalse);`
2. Another option is to rename my variable which is `existObjectsWithThisStudyId` to
   `noneObjectsExistWithThisStudyId` and then use requiredTrue. But it feels like a bad practice for naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can conditionally add the validator. Ex.

```
    setFieldValidators()
    {
      if(this.myBooleanValue) { //not required when your boolean is true
        this.myForm.controls.existObjectsWithThisStudyIdControl.setValidators([]);
      }
      else { //required when your boolean is false   
        this.myForm.controls.existObjectsWithThisStudyIdControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
      }
    this.myForm.controls.existObjectsWithThisStudyIdControl.updateValueAndValidity();
    this.myForm.controls.existObjectsWithThisStudyIdControl.markAsTouched();
    }
```

You can then set your validator on init, or on any event that that changes your  boolean value:

```
ngOnChanges()
{
  this.setFieldValidators();
}
```